# Prestashop Product details are not translated in frontend

Tags: prestashop

We are using Prestashop version PrestaShop™ 1.6.0.14 . We are facing issue in language translation like product details , category names in frontend are not getting translated.

Here we think the reason might be as shown here http://www.screencast.com/t/pfNoe4MdpzFz . We are not able to add/edit products in other language except the default i.e the language dropdown while adding product is not working anywhere.

While updating it says the product details is saved but the language dropdown value is not change, it remains the default selected language.

If you know any other reason of cause then please let us know and the way to recover it.

Comment: Could you check if you have any JS error at browser console log?

Answer (score 1):

I've found similar bug on PrestaShop 1.6.0.14

Check this post and try to fix your Configuration.php:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/200124-free-module-european-union-cookie-law-block-responsive/?p=2076917

Author: vekia

> Problem is with prestashop 1.6.0.14 where save process doesnt work
>   well in some environments.
>
> from what i see prestashop 1.6.1 contains fix for this problem. take a
>   look:
>   https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/classes/Configuration.php
>   line 370~ it contains code:
>
> ```
> if ($html)
>       {
>           foreach ($values as &$value)
>               $value = Tools::purifyHTML($value);
>           unset($value);
>       }
> ```
>
> and prestashop 1.6.0.14 contains bad code:
>
> ```
> if ($html)        
>       foreach ($values as &$value)    
>               $value = Tools::purifyHTML($value);
> ```
>
> This causing your problems! and it causes also problems with other,
>   even native PS modules that uses ps_configuration database to save
>   LANGUAGE variable values

In my case I was unable to save data for languages other than English (via module section).